# Add-AzureAccount : Index was out of range. Must be a non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

On 4th of August a new version of the Azure powershell module (0.8.7.1) was released.  In it is the ability to create credentials which you could then pass to the Add-AzureAccount function.  Add-AzureAccount allows you to pull in an account to work with in the current PowerShell session.

```
$userName = "buildmaster@someaccount.onmicrosoft.com"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "somepassword." -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName, $securePassword)

Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
```

This allowed me to get away from a popup window or messing with a settings file.

It seems to have stopped working!  Both Add-AzureAccount (which pops up a window) and the credential based way.  They now return an index was out of range issue.

```
Add-AzureAccount : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
At S:\QA\Azure Scripts\cm-azure-helpers.psm1:1128 char:5
+     Add-AzureAccount
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

Digging deeper with Fiddler shows that the OAuth call to the back end service seems to work.  I get a token returned.  But then I also get a 302 in the middle of the process stating that the page has moved.  I don't know if that redirect was there when it was working previously or not.

**Has anyone else experienced the Add-AzureAccount function just stop working like this?  And more importantly - have you found a way around it?**

**Update - More info**

I have now tried on several boxes under different azure accounts and seem to have the same results.  I get a valid auth token returned with a redirect in the middle (not sure if that is an issue or not) and then get the index was out of range.

I have done this with the following variations:

PS:3 Azure Module: 0.8.6
PS:3 Azure Module: 0.8.7
PS:4 Azure Module: 0.8.6
PS:4 Azure Module: 0.8.7

[image: Add-AzureAccount flow and version info]

Comment: Also, where get-azureaccount used to show the active accounts for the PS session it now shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what caused this error for me, and how I worked around it (I thought I was the only one who had seen this :))

What had happened is that I had accidentally added a bogus/empty subscription to my account. And this empty subscription had been set to my "default" subscription.

Run "get-azuresubscription -default" to see what your default subscription is. You can then "remove" any junk subscriptions using "remove-azuresubscription" command.

You can then of course set a new azure subscription for your "default" using PS.

I actually reported this to the Azure PowerShell team now to get a better error message during this scenario.
Hopefully this solved your problem, it's possible other errors manifest the same error message.

Comment: Checked the assigned default subscription and it appeared to be the right one.  Removed it any way and tried to re-add it.  This doesn't work though as I am currently unable to auth my account using add-azureaccount.  Something about the API response is different.  I have tried in 0.8.6 and 0.8.7 on multiple machines for various subscriptions and get the same index out of range issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a fiddler trace, you should see that right after the login call (where PowerShell passes in your username/password, there should be 1 or multiple calls to GET /subscriptions.

Check the response to see whether there is anything suspicious there. Like, any of them return an empty body, empty array, subscription with id, name, etc..

Comment: Working through your email response now!  I think you have nailed it.  The directory I was working through was removed which is where I think things started going down hill.  I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.  The "fix" was for me was to delete the files at C:\Users[username]AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell (esp. the WindowsAzureProfile.xml file). The next time I ran Add-AzureAccount, the necessary files were created and all was well.

Comment: I was able to locate and remove all those files.  And watch as both the headless (credential) and popup methods would create the files...then give the index was out of range error.  Thank you though!  A place to look for future issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId "id";
```

for login